# Is this some kind of Inverted sentences? "Circling the star Alpha Centauri, ages ago, was a planet unlike any other in the heavens -- Cybertron."

Tags: meaning

cited from Transformers:

> Circling the star Alpha Centauri, ages ago, was a planet unlike any other in the heavens -- Cybertron.

Is this some kind of Inverted sentences? Is the follow version, rewritten by me, has the same meaning?

> Cybertron was a planet that was circling the star Alpha Centauri ages ago.

Comment: Using the location at the beginning is quite common in English. Another example would be, "To the north of the country is the biggest lake in the region."